# Limma RNA-Seq analysis: using voom

Tags: r, bioconductor

I need to do **RNA-Seq** analysis with `limma` and I already have normalized count data for 61810 transcripts in two conditions (no replicates), i.e. a 61810*2 matrix. My "*design*" model matrix is :

```
(Intercept) sampletypestest
1           1               0
2           1               1

attr(,"assign")

[1] 0 1

attr(,"contrasts")

attr(,"contrasts")$sampletypes

[1] "contr.treatment
```

when I use `voom` on the data: `diff.exp <- voom(data,design)`, it gives the following error:

```
  Error in approxfun(l, rule = 2) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
```

Can anyone tell me what's the issue here?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow vivek, Now since you asked a question, Please make a reproducible example so that we can help you.also in R if you put `data()` on console you will get lot of dataset to work with , you can use one of them to reproduce the same problem. This can help you to get started. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , please also visit the help http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: How did you make your design matrix? In limma there is a function to do so. Did you follow the userguide?

Comment: @Llopis yah I made it as per the mannual. Although the manual has examples with replicates (2 wild type vs 3 mutants) but here I don't have any..

Comment: Probably you will get more help in the bioconductor mailing list, but the section 16 there is an example where they use the `voom` function(16.1.6).

Answer (score 2):

voom (and limma more generally) require replicates.  The whole purpose of voom is to estimate the mean-variance relationship.  It would work if you had any replicates at all in any of groups.  But you don't have any replicates, so you can't estimate any variances, so an error is inevitable.